# How to create a nonlocalized resource within an iOS App Bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to have a custom sound to be played when my application receives a notification, as part of the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6) this should be done in the following way:

`You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in Xcode, add the sound file to your project as a nonlocalized resource of the app bundle`

My question is how do you create a nonlocalized resource? Is it automatically created when you drag/drop the audio file into the Xcode project? Is it specified in the Info.plist?

I'm able to play the sound file using the following code:

```
if let buttonBeep = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("0897", type:"aiff") {
    self.buttonBeep = buttonBeep
}

buttonBeep?.volume = 1.0
buttonBeep?.play()
```

...

```
func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer?  {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("Player not available")
    }

    return audioPlayer
}
```

But no sound plays when a push notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

When you drag the sound file into Xcode, make sure that you check the box to "Add To Targets".